# How do I submit a new CellProcessor for inclusion in Super CSV?

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

I've written a simple custom CellProcessor for use with Super CSV.

It wraps the cell output to prevent losing leading zeroes when the CSV is opened in Excel.

For example, if the field is a zip code like this...  08330, Excel will normally convert it to a number and you will lose the leading zeroes.  However, if you wrap the value like this...   ="08330"   ...then it will be treated as a formula and the leading zeroes will be preserved.  The CellProcessor I've written just does that wrapping for you.

I'd like to submit it for inclusion in the Super CSV project, but I'm unsure how to do that.

Comment: just open a pull request

Comment: you assume I know how to use GitHub